# Custom slider with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the reproduce the next slider in jQuery. I can't change the design of the selector so I'm looking a way to reproduce it. The idea is to be a slideshow with auto-play and if you click on image of the selector you can change the page and the auto-play stops.

[image: Slider example]

The idea of the code is also have a fallback in text for non-javascript browsers and for better indexing (the blue area is a image). My actual code is:

```
<div id="index-slider">
    <div class="slides_container">

        <div class="index-slider-case">

            <div class="index-slider-fallback">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                <p>Proin at nibh ac diam eleifend mattis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
                <a href="/lorem-ipsum">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>

            <div class="index-slider-content">
                <a href="/lorem-ipsum">
                    <img src="lorem-ipsum.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And with jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $(".index-slider-fallback").remove(); // Remove the div's we don't need
    $(".index-slider-content").removeClass("hidden"); // Activate the image div's

});
```

I didn't found a plugin to reproduce something similar so I'm thinking if I have to do something custom or there is anyway to modify a plugin. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!